# How to implement Navigation Drawer in my activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am writing a simple coupon application, but I am struggling to implement a navigation drawer in my activity.

I have a toolbar with a tabbed navigation. I'd like to have a "hamburger" style button in my toolbar which will allow me to open my navigation drawer. I have no clue how to implement this.

I'd be extremely happy if someone helped me!

Photo of my layout in Android Studio:
[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".activities.MainActivity" android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorSecondaryDark"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:title="Makdolan Native"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:background="@color/colorSecondaryDark"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a `toolbar_layout.xml` file

As an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/dark_gray">

<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/menubutton_toolbar"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Add the lines below to your onCreate method in your activity:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.toolbar_layout)

    val view = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView()
```

To implement a touch listener to your toolbar you can simply call

```
var back = view.menubutton_toolbar as ImageButton;
back.setOnClickListener {
  //Open Drawer
  drawer?.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNDEFINED)
  if(drawer?.getDrawerLockMode(Gravity.LEFT) != DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED) {
            drawer?.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT)
        }
}
```

**UPDATE**

First of all we need a drawer layout like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_name_drawer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Then init the drawer in your MainActivity:

```
    var drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout) as DrawerLayout
    var toggle : ActionBarDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer, R.string.srn_drawer_open, R.string.srn_drawer_close)

    drawer?.addDrawerListener(toggle)
```

I hope this will help you ^^

Comment: Well, this solves the "hamburger" style button, but I'd like to have the whole Navigation Drawer which i don't know how to implement.

Comment: Do you know how can I implement this with my tabbed navigation?